# implicit const cast in templates

Tags: c++, const-cast

i ran across something similar to the below code snippet, which  throws a compiler error because its using a `const_iterator`. is there a reason why `vec.end()` in `std::copy` does not implicitly get a `const` cast ?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(20);
    vec.push_back(30);
    vector<int> copy_vec;
    vector<int>::const_iterator i = vec.begin();
    std::copy(i,vec.end(),back_inserter(copy_vec));
    cerr<<copy_vec.size()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need of `std::copy`, neither you need a pair of iterators.

Just do this:

```
vector<int> copy_vec(vec); //use the copy constructor!
```

And you're done!

As for your code why it is giving error, is because the first iterator to `std::copy` is a `const_iterator`, but the second iterator is just `iterator`. Both has to be same type, but they are not, and because of that the template argument deduction fails for `std::copy` which is a function template.

To understand this with an example, consider this simple code:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T a, T b) {}

int main()
{
    int a = 100;
    char b = 'A';
    f(a,b);
}
```

It is giving error (see [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/Y0VUT)):

```
prog.cpp:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(int&, char&)’
```

It doesn't compile because we're **relying on template argument deduction**. Since the type of the first parameter and second parameter is *exactly* same in the function template but we call this function passing `a` (which is `int`) as first argument and `b` (which is `char`) as second argument, it cannot deduce `T` uniquely from arguments of different types! *Please note that conversion is not considered during template argument deduction.*

However, if we **do not rely on template argument deduction**, and instead provide the template argument explicitly, then it would work (see [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/9cvMQ)):

```
f<int>(a,b);  //works!
```

It works as there is no need to deduce `T` from function arguments!

Similarly, if you provide the template argument for `std::copy`, then even your code would work (see [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/N6YJj)):

```
std::copy<vector<int>::const_iterator>(i,vec.end(),back_inserter(copy_vec));
       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ explicitly provide template argument!
```

It works because `iterator` can convert into `const_iterator`, but `const_iterator` cannot convert into `iterator` which means the following would give error (see [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/iTvWP)):

```
std::copy<vector<int>::iterator>(i,vec.end(),back_inserter(copy_vec));
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ non-const iterator!
```

Comment: actually above is just an example code i was more interested in figuring out why implicit const conversion does not occur

Comment: @keety: I have also explained that part. :-)

Comment: @keety: There are no type conversion,when Argument Dependent Lookup(ADL) for template functions.The data type has to be an exact match.

Comment: @keety: I also added more explanation, with a simple example!

Answer (score 1):

`vec` is a non-const vector, and so `end` will return a non-const iterator. Such an iterator actually cannot be implicitly converted to a const version, because they're separate classes.

Instead, use the two iterator constructor:

`vector<int> copy_vec(vec.begin(), vec.end());`

Comment: Why not simply `vector<int> copy_vec(vec)`? :P

Comment: You're wrong regarding it >> `Such an iterator actually cannot be implicitly converted to a const version, because they're separate classes.` That is not the reason why it is not working (see my answer for actual reason). Also, non-const iterator can implicitly convert into const iterator, for all kind of standard containers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here is that std::copy is declared to take three parameters.

The first two are of the same type, and you are passing `( const_iterator, vec.end () )` - and vec.end() is returning a non-const iterator (because vec is a non-const vector). This causes the compiler to reject the template for std::copy.

If you had a function like this:

```
void doit ( const std::vector<int> &vec, std::vector<int> &out ) {
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = vec.begin();
    std::copy(i,vec.end(),back_inserter(out));
    }
```

Then it will compile and work fine, because vec.end () will return a const_iterator.
Alternately, if you are using C++11, you can call vec.cend () to get a const_iterator.